# How can I export a Microsoft Office 365 Word online document to PDF without comments?

Tags: office-365, export, comments, pdf, microsoft-word

I have a Word document in Microsoft Office 365 Word Online. The document contains some comments. How can I export it to PDF without comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can click on View:

[image]

then Print:

[image]